# Pressing enter in tags field can inadvertently submit question

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, user-interface

When adding tags to a question since enter is the (or atleast an) auto complete key for the inline drop down list if the list isn't visible the enter key will cause the form submit and post the question. This behavior is counterintuitive and more than once has caused me to post my question prior to being finished.

Comment: What browser are you using? It's possible your browser forces this behavior regardless.

Comment: I noticed this behavior started happening with the bigger tag entering design which was introduced circa last month. Before then, I was able to use the enter key to confirm tags. This used to be a lot easier because I didn't have to use shuffle between using my keyboard and mouse. I am using Firefox.

Comment: Shouldn't this bug be re-opened again, as the behaviour changed? (see the edit in the [only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35460/193139))

Comment: @unor I believe it should.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this all the time... When I hit "enter" in a form field (with the exception of multi-line input fields), I *expect* it to submit the form - saves all that effort tabbing to the "submit" button.

The counter-intuitive bit for me is when the drop-down shows up at odd times and enter *doesn't* submit the form...

---

**Edit:** When I originally wrote this, hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> would complete the tag name being typed. You *could* use enter for this, but tab worked, so why bother...

Tab doesn't work anymore. So enter does two things, and double-tapping might not do what you expect.

Comment: Hitting enter should only submit the form in the tag field when *you're done choosing tags*. While in the act of choosing tags, the enter key should confirm the tags, as it did before this new UI design.

Comment: -1 having enter submit a form field inside of a live text area that uses enter for other operations like picking a value on an auto-complete list is **truly** counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Chris: the current behavior of the tag autocomplete is quite completely different from what it was when I wrote this. See my edit...