# Pressing enter in the edit reason field can inadvertently submit an edit suggestion

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, edits, user-interface

When writing an edit reason, I hit the Enter key by accident, and it submitted the edit.  Could this behaviour be removed?

I did not have edit privileges.  The edit was submitted to the review queue, for the attention of several trusted users.  But I really wanted to give them a clear reason, to explain why I suggested this edit.

I could not find a way to "undo" the edit suggestion and start again.

---

(This is a similar idea to the following feature requests, which have already been implemented: [Pressing enter in tags field can inadvertently submit question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35458/pressing-enter-in-tags-field-can-inadvertently-submit-question) and [Disable enter key for flag submission](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203877/disable-enter-key-for-flag-submission))

Comment: This is not a feature request, this is a request to remove a feature. Please don't.

Comment: @Mast subjective but fair :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Submitting a form may be a significant irrevocable action... In some cases this can be mitigated by an easy "undo" option.

In the situation you described, you can just edit the post again and improve your suggested edit (the edit itself, but also the edit summary). Yes, somebody (the OP perhaps) might already be reviewing the (half-finished) edit, but only if they're *very* fast.

Comment: Ah.  I think I might have done that before with edits, but the idea did not occur to me in this case, i.e. for the *edit reason*.

Answer (score 4):

I personally find this behavior useful. It makes sense to me to press Enter upon finishing up my edit summary and have that submit the edit. I don't want to see this behavior go away.

As far as your primary complaint with this feature, that you accidentally submit your suggested edits before you finish them: suggested edits aren't final once you submit them. You can edit your suggested edit by clicking the "edit" button again; your prior pending edit will be preloaded and any further edits you make will be folded into your prior edit suggestion.

That said, if you *really* run into it very often that it becomes an annoyance, you can head to https://stackapps.com/ where you can ask someone to write a user script for you to disable it. I personally haven't had any edits submitted accidentally and prematurely as a result of this feature, but if you encounter it frequently, that's an option.

Comment: You just cannot retract your edit suggestion.